# What is a good maximum log file size for an iPhone/Android app?

Tags: iphone, android, logging, mobile, rhomobile

I'm writing a mobile application (using Rhomobile, a cross-platform framework) that runs on iPhone and Android. The app contains a log file that overwrites itself when it hits its configurable maximum size.

In general, what is a good maximum log file size for an iPhone/Android app?

Comment: Depends on what you need the logfile for in the first place

Comment: What could you possibly need to log in an iPhone/Android app?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on a lot of things. Especially what you need the log file for. Are you sure you even need a log file?

As an iPhone and Android user I can tell you that I've never looked at a log file for any app that I've used. So chances are that your users will never even look at the log file. If it's not for the users I don't see why you should save it on the phone, since the user is the only one with access to the phone.

Also if the log file is overwritten when it reaches the maximum size, that indicates that only the last log entry is of interest (since it overwrites all the others). If that's the case the log file should always be the size of the last entry.

If you want a number I would say 256 KB (or less). That should be small enough to not bother anyone and big enough to log almost anything. However I'm still not convinced that you need that log.

Comment: This is for an enterprise app that I would like to troubleshoot in the field. Thus, I'd like for users to be able to send me their logs when they run into particular issues. (A feature of the framework I'm using is that it has a built-in logging API with a 'send' feature. When the log is sent, I store it in a SQL Server table.)

So, the log level I want is something that will allow as much detail without severely impacting the device/app performance. I was thinking there might be a ballpark range.